# I was wondering if anyone knew how to find the min value and a max value and find the timeframe between them?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

im working with a movie database I made and I wanted to make a select query that would separately select the the movie with the highest revenue and the movie with the lowest value and find the timeframe between them

i've tried to use the min and max functions to try to separately  select the lowest and the highest movies and tried to use datediff() to try and the timeframe between them. my code is below

```
SELECT  titles.title, min(financial_info.revenue),max(financial_info.revenue),
DATEDIFF(year, date(min(financial_info.revenue), date(max(financial.revenue)))

production_company.release_date  
from titles 
left join financial_info on titles.id = financial_info.id  
left join production_company on 
titles.imdb_id = production_company.imdb_id
```

I had aggregation error and a syntax error

Comment: Aside from parenthesis issues, `date(min(financial_info.revenue))` makes no sense in MySQL. See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

Comment: How are you grouping the values to determine `min/max`? When using aggregates, you should limit the scope to only the aggregate data, using subqueries to add on to the grouped values. Otherwise you would need to specify [`ANY_VALUE(column)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) to suppress the errors and risk undesired values being displayed.

Comment: I do! (I suspect there may be others)

Comment: so put the subquery in the group by part in order to find the difference between the dates?

Comment: do I have to hardcode the dates in order to find the difference between the dates?

Comment: First you need a subquery to find the revenue amounts, then you use those values to get the titles (and their accompanying information) that made those amounts, and **then** you can take the difference between their accompanying dates. _It can be done in one query, where the min-max revenue portion is a subquery._

Comment: What about movies with identical max and min revenue? For example 3 movies with max revenue and 8 movies with min?

Answer (score 0):

The general format for this kind of query would be:

```
SELECT stuff
   , maxB.Y - minB.Y -- Or, in this case DATEDIFF instead of minus
FROM (SELECT MIN(x) AS minX, MAX(x) AS maxX FROM a) AS minMax
INNER JOIN a AS minA ON minMax.minX = minA.X
INNER JOIN a AS maxA ON minMax.maxX = maxA.X
INNER JOIN b AS minB ON minA.b_id = minB.b_id
INNER JOIN b AS maxB ON maxA.b_id = maxB.b_id
;
```

You can end up with more than one result if there are multiple entries with the same revenue amount. (2 at min revenue and 3 at max revenue would yield 6 results).